# Old swap drive slows down boot time

Tags: boot, swap

I had an old swap device leftover from centos 7 that was deleted. Now whenever I boot my pc, Ubuntu has to take a minute and a half scanning for it. e. g. A start job is running for dev-mapper-centos\x2dswap.device, and i would like to know if there is a way I can stop this.

Comment: look for it in `/etc/fstab` (file system table), and if there comment it out by adding a "#" (no quotes) at the start of the line. You could delete it too, but commenting it out makes it easier to restore if you touch the wrong line.  Note: the file requires elevated privileges, so use a command like `sudo vim /etc/fstab` to edit it (replacing vim with your favorite editor)

Comment: I tried this first but there does not seem to be an entry

Comment: check UUID entries of swap partitions; though the dev-mapper but implies 'lvm' to me...  check `lvdisplay` to confirm its not used; but I'm not sure how to delete a non-present..

Comment: As i said this is an old hard disk that i no longer own.

Comment: There is only one swap partition and it is the internal swap

Comment: explore `lvremove` (logical volume remove) .. (suspicion only; use only with volumes you aren't using! or maybe wait for someone who uses lvm regularly or in their work..)

Comment: @guiverc it worked, there was one entry at fstab that was missing, I had removed it physically, and it waited for 90s as it was missing. I think that first comment could be a good answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

look for it in `/etc/fstab` (file system table), and if there comment it out by adding a "#" (no quotes) at the start of the line. You could delete it too, but commenting it out makes it easier to restore if you touch the wrong line.

Note: the file requires elevated privileges, so use a command like `sudo vim /etc/fstab` to edit it (replacing `vim` with your favorite editor)

(*initial comment added as an answer as suggested by @aquarius-power who found it helpful*)